# Flutter - PlatformException - Failed to generate key pair

Tags: flutter

I developed a simple demo app using [mek_stripe_terminal](https://pub.dev/packages/mek_stripe_terminal). But while it works fine on Android 12 and above devices, I get the following error on an Android 11 device.

This is the error stacktrace captured by crashlytics:

```
Fatal Exception: io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterError: PlatformException(error, Failed to generate key pair, null, java.security.ProviderException: Failed to generate key pair
    at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreKeyPairGeneratorSpi.generateKeystoreKeyPair(AndroidKeyStoreKeyPairGeneratorSpi.java:515)
    at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreKeyPairGeneratorSpi.generateKeyPair(AndroidKeyStoreKeyPairGeneratorSpi.java:471)
    at java.security.KeyPairGenerator$Delegate.generateKeyPair(KeyPairGenerator.java:727)
    at java.security.KeyPairGenerator.genKeyPair(KeyPairGenerator.java:497)
    at com.stripe.cots.common.compatibility.PreFlightChecks.initialize(Unknown Source:87)
    at com.stripe.stripeterminal.internal.common.adapter.CotsClient.initializeKeys(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.stripe.stripeterminal.internal.common.adapter.CotsAdapter.initKeystore(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.stripe.stripeterminal.Terminal$Companion.initTerminal(SourceFile:3)
    at com.stripe.stripeterminal.Terminal$Companion.initTerminal(SourceFile:2)
    at s6.c.g(Unknown Source:109)
    at t6.m1$b.b(Unknown Source:393)
    at t6.m1$b.a(Unknown Source:0)
    at t6.l1.a(Unknown Source:2)
    at k4.j$a.a(Unknown Source:17)
    at c4.c.l(Unknown Source:18)
    at c4.c.m(Unknown Source:40)
    at c4.c.i(Unknown Source:0)
    at c4.b.run(Unknown Source:12)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7664)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
Caused by: android.security.KeyStoreException: Unknown error
    at android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore.java:1301)
    ... 25 more
)
       at StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope(message_codecs.dart:651)
       at MethodChannel._invokeMethod(platform_channel.dart:322)
       at _$TerminalPlatform.init(terminal_platform.api.dart:27)
       at Terminal.getInstance.<fn>(terminal.dart:52)
       at _HomeViewState._initTerminal(home.dart:102)
```

[Device informations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttDEQ.png)

The error occurs during the process of initializing our app's Stripe Terminal SDK.

```
final terminal = await Terminal.getInstance(
    fetchToken: _fetchConnectionToken,
  );

 Future<String> _fetchConnectionToken() async {
    var token = await _api.createTerminalConnectionToken();
    return token;
  }

  Future<String> createTerminalConnectionToken() async {
    try {
      final terminalToken =
          await _stripe.client.post('/terminal/connection_tokens');
      return terminalToken['secret'] as String;
    } catch (error) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

[Error stacktrace - firebase image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7iC8.png)

Flutter version: 3.16.0 (stable channel)
mek_stripe_terminal: ^3.2.0

I would like to know if there are any suggestions or updates to resolve this issue. I'm also wondering if other users are experiencing this issue and if there is a potential workaround.

https://github.com/BreX900/mek-packages/issues/47